# Percentage within range with minimum not zero

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a group of numbers for which I need to assign a percentage score;  however, the lowest value does not equal 0% but 75%. To get started, 133.9 = 100%, 1.47 = 75%, and there are eleven additional values inbetween that need a percentage score based on that range.

What's the easiest way to run this comparison?

Comment: This is not belongs here, may be at http://superuser.com/ you will find a help

Comment: @pnuts my basis for that are redirecting the OP to a better place for asking such question, a place which he will find a better help, and for my opinion this question is not about programming, and your ref(which I didn't see before) proves that this is a pretty confusing point, which described enough in [that answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261943/1638739)

Comment: @pnuts well, I think may be you are right at this point, but I didn't vote to close, I falgged it and there is no option to un-flag.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in A1 (133.9) to A13 (1.47) with 1 (100% in B1) and .75 (75% in B13) please try in B2 and copied down to B12:

```
=B$13+(A2-A$13)*(B$1-B$13)/(A$1-A$13)
```

Alternatively, in B1 and copied down to B13:

```
=0.0019*A1+0.7472
```